# What causes "apply_selection_policy_once: prefer use of removable GPUs" on High Sierra

Tags: macos, opengl

**Issue:**

Among numerous macOS High Sierra installs in my user base, only one user is getting the following error with my application Isadora:

```
apply_selection_policy_once: prefer use of removable GPUs (via com.troikatronix.isadora(preferences):GPUSelectionPolicy->preferRemovable)
```

This appears during startup of the app, and leads to a crash upon the first attempt to create a shared OpenGL context.

**Background**

This is not a message that is being generated by my software directly. Instead I can only infer it is being generated by the OpenGL drivers or the operating system itsef.

This message seems to refer to a plist property called GPUSelectionPolicy [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/gpuselectionpolicy) that has to do with use of an eGPU.

The user does not have an eGPU attached to the computer at the time this error is generated, but he has had an eGPU attached previously. He has the NVIDIA Driver Manager running, but has selected "Default macOS Graphics Driver"

**Attempts to Fix**

Since this property was not included in my app's plist, my immediate resposne was to add it an set the value to "avoidRemovable" to force the operating system avoid eGPUs entirely. This did not solve the problem.

The part of the message that says "com.troikatronix.isadora(preferences)" would seem to indicate this message is coming from the file at ~/Library/Preferences/com.troikatronix.isadora.

I have instructed the user to try these fixes

1. Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.troikatronix.isadora and then restart the program
2. Create a fresh user account, restart computer and log in, then start the program
3. Create a new High Sierra partition on his driver or an external, and see if the crash persists

I am awaiting his reply on these tests but wanted to get this error posted in case some clever person out there offers an immediate answer.

(Note: A google search for the text "apply_selection_policy_once" on Google returns exacty one result, which does not discuss this message. So seems to be something quite rare.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem but the error has slightly different, which is

```
2019-07-28 00:50:09.962 Wireshark[13896:168862] apply_selection_policy_once: prefer use of removable GPUs (via org.wireshark.Wireshark:GPUSelectionPolicy->preferRemovable)
```

I am exactly same with your background except my eGPU is Blackmagic eGPU:

- **I** does not have an eGPU attached to the computer at the time this error is generated, but **I have** had an **Blackmagic** eGPU attached previously.

And your suggestion I tried and the problem still not solve.

- Completely uninstall the application (wireshark)
- Create a new user account
- Reinstall macOS
- Partitioning the hard disk and install a new macOS
- NVRAM (press command + option + P + R when start)

Moreover, the blackmagic eGPU is completely not work after I installed wireshark. Another words, the computer will crash after I plug in the Blackmagic eGPU **EVERY TIME**

Hope my situation can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS creates a preferences file automatically for each application using the application. This file needs to be deleted to solve the problem.

The solution is as follows:

1. Delete the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.XXX.plist, where XXX is the Bundle Identifier of your application as found in the Info.plist file in your application package. In my case it XXX was "troikatronix.isadora" so the full file name was

   ```
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.troikatronix.isadora.plist
   ```
2. Restart the computer
3. Restart the application

I have added the "GPUSelectionPolicy" property to the Info.plist file, with the value "avoidRemovable" to hopefully prevent this problem in the future.

However, it is important to note that the solution above seemed to work for a previous version that did not have the GPUSelectionPolicy property set in the Info.plist file.

I remain unclear how this problem came into being in the first place. If you have further information on how this could occur, please add them to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I got the CLI output `apply_selection_policy_once: prefer use of removable GPUs` in the embedded terminal of Visual Studio Code, because I had *Prefer External GPU* enabled on the Visual Studio Code application (right-click in Finder, then *Get Info*). Apparently it propagates the preference down to child processes. Unchecking the tick box solved the problem for me.

[image]